# javascript scroll text vertically to next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have words wrapped in spans and I am highlighting text words as lyrics while song plays (timed by seconds).

My question would be is there a way to detect when highlighted text will run of the bottom of the container (parent overflow wrapper) so I move the text to next line, or maybe by few lines to show the next incoming highlighted lines. I can give all spans different ids if necessary. I could use scrollTop on inner-wrap div, but how would I calculate position of highlighted words?

For example, when this words with class red go out:

```css
#wrap{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ccc;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.red{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="inner-wrap">
<span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span class="red">Lorem</span> <span class="red">ipsum</span> <span class="red">dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. The position of the `<span>` within the wrapper is determined using its `offsetTop`. The wrapper is then scrolled to that position using its `scrollTop` property.

```js
// Example data, <span>ified
var wrap = document.querySelector("#wrap");
wrap.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. "
  .repeat(30).split(" ")
  .map(w => `<span>${w}</span>`).join(" ");
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("#wrap span");
var selected = null;

// Scroll to span function, also highlights the span
function scrollTo(span) {
  // Highlighting
  if (selected) {
    selected.className = "";
  }
  span.className = "red";
  selected = span;

  // Actual scrolling (span is centered in the wrapper)
  wrap.scrollTop = span.offsetTop - 35;
}

// Button listener
document.querySelector("#button").onclick = function() {
  scrollTo(spans[Math.floor(Math.random() * spans.length)]);
};
```

```css
#wrap {
  height: 70px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
<button id="button">Select random span</button>
```

Comment: Why is this getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: wrap.scroll is not a function ?

Comment: @Toniq Not sure, try now?

Comment: I am still getting an error, dont you? {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: wrap.scroll is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 39,
  "colno": 8
}

Comment: @Toniq Okay, I changed it to `scrollTop`. I thought `scroll` was well supported, but maybe not.